# GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps-api-3, google-drive-api

I am Developing an `Android` app which is using `com.google.api.client` jar file.
But when i run the project, I encountered that error.

Anyone have an idea on how to handle that exception?

**Exception Generated:=**

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException

Any Suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Make it clear and understandable to the readers.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException), `GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException` wraps a GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException into an [`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html?is-external=true) so it can be caught directly.

Example usage:

```
} catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
  myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
          availabilityException.getConnectionStatusCode(),
          myActivity,
          MyActivity.REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
      dialog.show();
    }
  });
```

Use [`getConnectionStatusCode()`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException#getConnectionStatusCode()) to display the error dialog. Alternatively, use [`getCause()`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException.html#getCause()) to get the wrapped `GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException`.

Comment: can you tell me generate this exception which problem occure ?